# Xcode: Incorrect checksum for freed objects?

Tags: c, malloc, breakpoints

I seem to be getting a sigabrt crash every once in a while (not every time).

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff8884644c0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.
```

Now, I know that means I'm probably attempting to access, or change an object after calling free() on it, but I was wondering how to find out what object it's referring to, using the memory address listed above. Thanks!

This is what I see before it crashes (It crashes on NSLog):

[image]

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running? If this is Linux/UNIX, you should be able to get a core-dump (you may have to enable them first), and then load it into `gdb` or any suitable debugger. From there, you should be able to identify the object pointed to by that address by examining the call stack, the symbol table, dumping memory, etc. Or you can just do what the error suggests and set a breakpoint in `malloc_error_break`.

Comment: I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and using Xcode 6.3.1

Comment: I've never developed in OS X, but from what I understand it's Unix-based, so you should be able to get a core dump. Looking at a core dump might not be the fastest or easiest way to identify the leaked object though (depending on the complexity of your code), so you may want to consider other options as well, such as jarmod's suggestion of dmalloc. You may also want to add an OS X tag here so you can get help from people with more experience with OS X, Xcode, etc.

Comment: I get this error message occasionally after compiling a bog-standard C++ program in XCode. It occurs straight after compilation, then doesn't recur when I run again. It may have something to do with the IDE hanging onto debug binary material, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Update to my last comment: I noticed the error occuring after successful compilation, but possible before an 'indexing' message in the IDE - perhaps it's got something to do with XCode's indexing (ie. parsing) of your code for things like auto-complete etc.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use a debug malloc replacement such as [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/) that can help you track source file & line number of malloc/free calls.